# IOS7 tableview bottom extra space in the viewcontrol

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I made a `view` that is embed by a `navigationbar` `view`. And the issue is the `tableview` cannot overlap the extra space at the bottom of `view`. Please review the picture.
 [image]

I made the view background color to be green, so you can see the extra space on the bottom clearly.

No matter I set the `uitableview` height to be more than `"568"`, nor set the extend edges disselect the "under the top bars", the extra space is always existed.

Could you give me some advises? I used `Xcode 5` and `IOS SDK 7.0`.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried everything to fix it. But I don't why all methods are failed. So I re-draw the nib in storyboard, the issues ever happen. It's strange. Maybe I move the nib from Xcode 4 to Xcode 5, which cause the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your navigation bar is translucent. In IOS 7, the translucent property becomes YES in default. Thats why your tableview appears in the top. In order to solve this you have to set the navigation bar's translucent as NO after creating your navigation controller object just like:

```
UINavigationController *navCtrl1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:home];
navCtrl1.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: I tired it. But it didn't work. I set the translucent "NO" in the root view of navigation view and current view.  Opps~~  but thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[image: also tried this one]

```
float systemVersion=[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
    if(systemVersion>=7.0f)
    {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;

    }
```

tried this in your `viewDidLaod()`.

Comment: Thanks, I tired it too, but not works either. I have tried to rebuild my nib, I found if I draw a new tableview in the storyboard, it will be OK, no extra space on bottom. Very Weird